# Power Query Preview Top and Order By

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Is there a way to keep Power Query from using `ORDER BY` when getting preview data?

I am trying to work with a table in SQL Server that contains 373 million records.  The Power Query Editor wants to produce a preview.  The M code for the "Navigate" step looks like...

```
Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="TableName"]}[Data]
```

...and it produces SQL that looks like...

```
select top 4096 [$Ordered].[ThisID]
, [$Ordered].[ThatID]
, [$Ordered].
    <bunch 
    of other 
    columns>

from [dbo].[TableName] as [$Ordered]

order by [$Ordered].[ThisID]
, [$Ordered].[ThatID]
```

`ThisID` and `ThatID` are `int`s.  These two columns make up the primary key, so the combination of them is indexed.  But indexed or not, this query wants to order 373 million records by 2 variables before returning a handful of rows that may as well be random given the context.  This query could take a very long time (hours?) to run, so **it times out and I have nothing to work with** (not even column names).  What I need would take less than 1 second.  (Basically, remove the ORDER BY clause.)

How can I change the number of rows returned?  I think I need 100 - 400, not 4096.

How can I tell the Power Query Editor to not care about which records are in the preview (no `ORDER BY`)?

These feel like they should be settings (not M code) but I am not seeing anything in the options to control this behavior.

I have a bunch of other tables in my model.  Will this one table need to be done using pass-thru SQL?  Will that still work in Direct Query mode?

Can this problem be solved by changing the M code in the Advanced Editor?

Comment: You can try the option Direct query with top number of row selection.

Comment: I don't see that option.  Under DirectQuery, I only see "Allow end users to change SQP variables for this report".  Where would I find "Direct query with top number of row selection"?

Comment: You can write your raw query under advanced option for direct query.

Comment: So for nontrivial databases, Power BI requires the developer to write SQL?  So what is the GUI there for?  That doesn't seem right.  There must be a setting.  Hopefully some Power BI guru will notice this question.

Comment: @mkRabbani - No offense.  I hadn't seen your profile yet.  I'm guessing from the numbers that you are a Power BI guru.  But if that's the best answer, Power BI doesn't seem to be a real product yet.  I'm trying to perform a very simple task that shouldn't require me to write any code.